# If i write in assembly or machine language, will the program work on any computer with a compatible processor?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

Basically, i'm wanting to know if i can use either machine or assembly language to write a program that will work on any computer with an x86 processor, despite differences in operating systems. For example, you run a program and no matter what computer it's on, it'll display "Hello, World!"
I know it's a little crazy to want to know either of these to languages, but i figure it's an incredible thing to learn, so why not?

Answer (score 2):

In General, No.

Different OS's will have different support for API functions, and support different hardware at different addresses.

If you want to cover the largest amount of platforms, then java is probably the way to go.

Comment: my primary programming language is java. i'm just learning assembly for the fun of it.

Answer (score 2):

No, programs are highly dependent on the operating system. To write output, such as "Hello, world!", a program generally makes a request to the operating system. Typically, the program will put the arguments for the request in a place specified by the operating system (e.g., the `EAX` register) and then execute an instruction that requests service from the operating system.

Operating system requests are typically coded by number or some similar scheme. So to request writing characters to an output stream, you put one number in `EAX`. To open a file, you use another number, et cetera. Obviously, the codes differ from operating system to operating system. (These requests are commonly wrapped in library calls. When you call a library like "write", it contains instructions to do something similar to what I describe above.)

Even if you wanted to "do it yourself" and write to the screen by manipulating hardware, there are some problems. One, the operating system has to let you have access to the hardware. Most systems these days prevent user-mode programs from having direct access to the hardware. Two, your program has to be designed for particular hardware. Maybe there is an old-style BIOS that you can send characters to, or maybe there is some modern firmware in the system. You need different methods to work with different firmware or any different components outside the CPU.

That said, it might not be impossible to write an assembly language program that runs on several different operating systems. There are some programs (called [polyglots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing))) written in multiple high-level languages simultaneously, like both FORTRAN and C. For example, a program might start with a "C" in a column that indicates it is a comment in FORTRAN, but the first line is valid C code. And that C code can start a comment. Subsequent lines are then arranged so they are either FORTRAN code and C comments or FORTRAN comments and C code. It might be possible to do something similar with an executable file, so that two different operating systems accept it as an executable file, and it prints "Hello, world!" on each (or, better yet, does something different on each).

The DOS .COM format might be good for this, since it is a raw binary file. If the first few bytes of an executable file for another system can be the bytes that represent a jump instruction, then the .COM file could cause a jump to somewhere else in the file, where you can arrange for there to be whatever bytes you like, while the file is otherwise an executable file for the other system.

This is, of course, not the intended way to design executable files, and it is not an easy task.

It may be impossible for most file formats other than .COM because most object or executable file formats require the first two or four bytes of the file to be a [magic number that identifies the file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).  A multi-platform executable with the widely-used ELF format might be possible if you can find a way to have different platforms see different values for the fields within the ELF file that identify which platform its for.

Answer (score 1):

"It depends"

If you want an actual stand alone executable binary, then the answer is no.  However if you are just looking to write a snippet of assembly, then embed it in a larger executable the answer is "yes"; however you would not be allowed to invoke any OS specific features within that blob of assembly code.  So, you probably can't realize this dream of creating a single assembly program that prints out "Hello world" on multiple operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Baloney.  The MACHINE LANGUAGE for the x86 computers does not change from machine to machine.  what they do is to add instructions etc.  if you wanted the program to do something more involved than 'hello world' then the way to accomplish that would be a little different depending on how the h/w handled paging, etc..  for a small program that didn't jump around in ram it would be pretty much the same for each.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Operating systems don't ordinarily just start executing the first byte of a binary program.  What they do instead is set up the address space for the application, which will include things like how big it wants its call stack to be, what values it wants to preassigned to constants, and what parts of the binary file should be loaded as executable code, rather than writable data.

The way a binary program instructs the operating system how it wants to have it's address space configured varies from operating system to operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no is your answer. You can write, say, x86 assembly and it will do the same thing on Linux, Mac OS X, and MS Windows ... But by do the same thing, I mean literally it will take data from the same place, perform the same operations and store it back somewhere in memory.

So in this way, you can do fast 3d math or something in the same way on all platforms, but the way you get data into your assembly routine and out of it and what you use it for will be different on all platforms. So you can't "display" hello world on any OS, but you can certainly put the characters "hello world" (or a set of transformed vertecies) into memory somewhere so your OS specific code can pull it out and use it.